# Passing arguments via rqt_launch plugin (ROS Launch GUI)

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm trying to pass an argument to my node via the rqt pluging rqt_launch.
But, whatever I type in the GUI into the field "arguments", the values are not passed to my node. Always the default value is passed.

Here the code of my launch-file:

```
<launch>
<arg name="foo" default="string"/>
<node name="some_other_node" pkg="some_other_pkg" type="some_other_type" />
<node name="node_with_arg" pkg="the_pkg" type="the_type" args="$(arg foo)"/>
</launch>
```

If I start it via command line and roslaunch, everthing is fine, e.g.:

```
roslaunch name.launch foo:=my_string
```

But the same syntax with `foo:=my_string` is not working in the ROS Launch GUI in the arguments field.
What is the correct syntax to set an argument via rqt_launch plugin?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/79121/passing-arguments-via-rqt_launch-plugin-(ros-launch-gui)/) by [Sebastian G](https://answers.ros.org/users/6280/sebastian-g/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-09-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Passing argument is not yet implemented unfortunately, and currently I don't have an extra gear to add that feature. If you or anyone could send a patch toward its devel repository https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_common_plugins/issues I'm happy to review it.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-09-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0